# Dirty Bash hack to run the ssh connections in the Parallel mode

Tags: bash, shell

A Few years back I used to opt the below method to run the shell program in a Parallel way to open multiple ssh session at a time to get a quick result.

I know there are various other good utilities available, however due to some pressing needs I've to use this way, this dirty piece of code works well however I would like to know if there are some suggestion to improve it further considering the fact I have to use it for some compelling reasons over other better tools.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(date) Starting the SSH Connection Check...."
#set -x

read -rsp $'Please Enter password below: ' SSHPASS
export SSHPASS
SSH_Connection () {
    hostTarget=${1}
    sshpass -e ssh -q "${hostTarget}" "true" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=60 2>>/dev/null
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
    then
        echo  "$CurrntTime $MachineName   : SSH connection is Up"
    elif [[ $? -eq 255 ]]
        then
        echo  "$CurrntTime $MachineName   : SSH Authentication Failed"
    elif [[ $? -eq 2 ]]
        then
        echo  "$CurrntTime $MachineName   : SSH connection is Down"
    elif [[ $? -eq 1 ]]
        then
        echo  "$CurrntTime $MachineName   : SSH Authentication Failed"
    else
        echo  "$CurrntTime $MachineName   : SSH connection is Down"
    fi
}

HostList=$(<~/host2)

CurrntTime=$(date +'%m/%d/%Y %T')

for MachineName in ${HostList}
do
    SSH_Connection "${MachineName}" &
done
# wait for all outstanding background jobs to complete before continuing
wait
# at last clear the exported variable containing the password
unset SSHPASS
```

Comment: Do you have compelling reasons for not using ssh keys?  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server

Comment: Yes.. I can not supply keys even. I know about ssh keys and another methods as well even about pssh but as i mentioned, its not always where we have liberty to choose our freedom over companies policies for any reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only part I would change are the chained `if` statements. Use `case`:

```
CurrntTime="some_timestamp"
MachineName="some_host"
for retval in 0 255 2 1 8; do
   echo "Testing exitcode ${retval}"
   case ${retval} in
   0)
        echo  "$CurrntTime $MachineName   : SSH connection is Up";;
   255)
        echo  "$CurrntTime $MachineName   : SSH Authentication Failed";;
   2)
        echo  "$CurrntTime $MachineName   : SSH connection is Down";;
   1)
        echo  "$CurrntTime $MachineName   : SSH Authentication Failed";;
   *)
        echo  "$CurrntTime $MachineName   : SSH connection is Down";;
   esac
done
```

More optimisation is not needed. The alternative beneath is slightly shorter but makes the code harder to read (more fun, though):

```
CurrntTime="some_timestamp"
MachineName="some_host"

ssh_err_0="connection is Up"
ssh_err_1="Authentication Failed"
ssh_err_2="connection is Down"
ssh_err_255="Authentication Failed"
ssh_err_other="connection is Down"

for retval in 0 255 2 1 8; do
   echo "Testing exitcode ${retval}"
   printf "%s" "$CurrntTime $MachineName   : SSH "
   case ${retval} in
   0|1|2|255)
      message="ssh_err_${retval}"
      echo "${!message}";;
   *)
      echo "${ssh_err_other}";;
   esac
done
```

When you use the first `case` in the total script, and move the `SSH_Connection()` function to the start of the script, it would be

```
#!/bin/bash

SSH_Connection () {
    hostTarget=${1}
    sshpass -e ssh -q "${hostTarget}" "true" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
       -o ConnectTimeout=60 2>/dev/null

    case $? in
    0)
       echo  "$CurrntTime $hostTarget: SSH connection is Up";;
    255)
       echo  "$CurrntTime $hostTarget: SSH Authentication Failed";;
    2)
       echo  "$CurrntTime $hostTarget: SSH connection is Down";;
    1)
       echo  "$CurrntTime $hostTarget: SSH Authentication Failed";;
    *)
       echo  "$CurrntTime $hostTarget: SSH connection is Down";;
    esac
}

echo "$(date) Starting the SSH Connection Check...."

read -rsp $'Please Enter password below: ' SSHPASS
export SSHPASS

HostList=$(<~/host2)

CurrntTime=$(date +'%m/%d/%Y %T')

for MachineName in ${HostList}; do
   SSH_Connection "${MachineName}" &
done
# wait for all outstanding background jobs to complete before continuing
wait
# at last clear the exported variable containing the password
unset SSHPASS
```

I did not move the `CurrentTime=$(..)` inside the function. When you want to see the date/time after the `ssh` is finished, then you will need to store the exit code in a variable:

```
...
sshpass -e ssh ...
retval=$?
CurrentTime=$(date +'%m/%d/%Y %T')
case ${retval} in ...
```

Comment: Thanks Walter, How the complete code would look like then, can your formulate the code with you adjustment.

Comment: Is the code clear for you?